# 403 error page in jboss on server level(single error page and single entry for the page for all the war files)

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, http-status-code-403, server

I have four war files in the jboss 7 deployments folder.Each war file has its own web.xml and there is one entry for 403 error in each web.xml.

But I want only one entry for all the war files(modules) for 403 error.If anywhere 403 error come in the jboss, it should be redirect to same page.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Where do you expect the common 403 error page to be?

Comment: The page is in ROOT.war inside deployments..all the 403 error should redirect to that page only.How to define this globally for all the modules(war files)?